# JQuery rollover state and "Current" items

Tags: jquery

I have a simple JQuery rollover. The problem is, there is always one "current" item and I am using Jquery to change that current item accordingly. I am using the .hover function to change the hover colors based on page name. Right now, everything works fine, except that as soon as you roll over the current item, it loses it's "current" color and blanks just like the rest of the nav items. Here is a check I tried but it doesn't work. Basically, checking to see if the item does not have the color, if it doesn't then run the rollover function.

What am I doing wrong and is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

```
if (jQuery('.sub_navigation li a').css('color') != '#F37321') {
    jQuery(".sub_navigation li a").hover(function () {
        jQuery(this).css({'color' : '#F37321'});
    }, function () {
        var cssObj = {'color' : ''};
        jQuery(this).css(cssObj);
    });
} /*end if */
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use classes instead of inline styles. Then, you can add and remove the .hover class without having to worry about the .current class being affected.

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".sub_navigation li a").hover(
    function () { $(this).addClass('hover'); }
  , function () { $(this).removeClass('hover'); });
  });

</script>

<style>
  .hover {
    color: #F37321;
  }
  .current {
    color: #F37321;
  }
</style>

<ul class="sub_navigation">
  <li><a class="current">I am current</a></li>
  <li><a>I am not</a></li>
  <li><a>Neither am I</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Agreed.  Although I would use a different name than hover as not everyone browses with a mouse ;)  Google also recommends using classes.  Find out more in their tutorials: http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Am i right in understanding that you want the color to be on the latest element hover'ed? But not removed from the current element if hovered over again?

Try something like (using a .current class for the control)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".sub_navigation li a").hover(function () {
        jQuery(".sub_navigation li a.current").removeClass('current');
        jQuery(this).addClass('current');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `if` statement isn't doing what you think it is.  You are only testing the color of the **first** link, never anything else. `jQuery('.sub_navigation li a')` selects all `sub_navigation` links and `.css` acts on the first item in that group.

Second, why are you using `cssObj`?  While not wrong, it seems like a long way to just say `.css({'color' : ''})`.

To do what you are asking, you could do a couple of things.  One would be to set a class on your current link and filter that out:

```
jQuery(".sub_navigation li a :not('.current')").hover(function () {
         jQuery(this).css({'color' : '#F37321'});
}, function () {
         jQuery(this).css({'color' : ''});
});
```

Another would be to have your hover style be a class:

```
jQuery(".sub_navigation li a").hover(function () {
         jQuery(this).addClass('hoverClass');
}, function () {
         jQuery(this).removeClass('hoverClass');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE:

Since you have already specified that your using a PHP script in Wordpress to style the current page link, then all your needing is to style each page with the appropriate navigation colors. So what you want to do is set up a source script that simply has basic functions containing a hover jQuery script with the color of your desire. Like so:

```
function redHover() {
  $('.subnavigation li a').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('red');
  });
}

function blueHover() {
  $('.subnavigation li a').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('blue');
  });
}

function greenHover() {
  $('.subnavigation li a').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('green');
  });
}
```

Then create a css file with the classes you specified in the functions:

```
.red {
  color: #FF0000;
}
.blue {
  color: #3366FF;
}
.green {
  color: #009900;
}
```

Then just specify the function you want on the page of your desire:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  redHover(); //or
  blueHOver(); //or
  greenHover();
});
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried this and I'm having some trouble. Let me back up a bit. One reason I am using the JQuery hover state in the first place is that I have four areas on the site. Each area has it's own color for rollovers etc. So I have base colors set in CSS. Once you load a particular page, I use JQuery to change that CSS color state. Of course, you can't change a:hover with JQuery so I have to use this function. I'm using a Wordpress PHP function to detect which page is loaded. Wordpress already adds the "current" page class to the li which makes things handy.

Comment: ahhh I reread your question and now I understand what you want a little better. If you have a link or live environment could you post it? Visual examples might help reinforce your question.

Comment: Thanks all. I haven't had a chance to implement anything yet as the client is freaking out about a JQuery scalable background issue I also posted about. Urgh. It's been one of those weeks. I'll post back if this works though it looks like it will.